# How to get text for a root element using lxml?

Tags: python, lxml

I'm completely stumped why lxml `.text` will give me the text for a child tag but for the root tag.

```
some_tag = etree.fromstring('<some_tag class="abc"><strong>Hello</strong> World</some_tag>')

some_tag.find("strong")
Out[195]: <Element strong at 0x7427d00>

some_tag.find("strong").text
Out[196]: 'Hello'

some_tag
Out[197]: <Element some_tag at 0x7bee508>

some_tag.text
```

`some_tag.find("strong").text` returns the text between the `<strong>` tag.

I expect `some_tag.text` to return everything between `<some_tag> ... </some_tag>`

Expected:

```
<strong>Hello</strong> World
```

Instead, it returns nothing.

Answer (score 10):

```
from lxml import etree

XML = '<some_tag class="abc"><strong>Hello</strong> World</some_tag>'

some_tag = etree.fromstring(XML)

for element in some_tag:
    print element.tag, element.text, element.tail
```

Output:

```
strong Hello  World
```

For information on the `.text` and `.tail` properties, see:

- http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-contain-text
- http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pylxml/web/etree-view.html

To get exactly the result that you expected, use

```
print etree.tostring(some_tag.find("strong"))
```

Output:

```
<strong>Hello</strong> World
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the missing text here

```
>>> some_tag.find("strong").tail
' World'
```

Look at http://lxml.de/tutorial.html and search for "tail".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question but you have 2 main solutions in parsing :

DOMParser : depending the langage, it's node.getNodeValue();

SAXParser : depending the langage, but in java for example is in the fonction : characters(...)

I haven't the time to search on google but in python, I know MiniDOM (a DOM parser) :
http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/11/12/python-parsing-xml-with-minidom/

I hope my answer can help you.

Comment: I tried the minidom but that doesn't seem to work either.

`some_tag_md = minidom.parseString('<some_tag class="abc"><strong>Hello</strong> World</some_tag>')`

`some_tag_md.nodeValue`

:/

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
comp = [ etree.tostring(e) for e in some_tag]
print ''.join(comp[0])
```

EDITED: Thanks @mzjin for putting me on the right track

Answer (score 0):

You have to use inbuilt lxml method to retrieve all the text between the tag.

```
  from lxml import etree
  xml='''<some_tag class="abc"><strong>Hello</strong> World</some_tag>'''
  tree = etree.fromstring(xml)
  print(''.join(tree.xpath('//text()')))
```